# Does interacting with highlighted objects in Masyaf accomplish anything?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In the castle at Masyaf in the beginning of the game, there are several items (a table, a bookcase, a stack of books) that are highlighted and give you an "interact" option. Doing so causes a ghost or memory of Altaïr to appear in the room and do some gesturing.

Does interacting with these objects have any effect on the gameplay or story? Do you miss anything by not interacting with these objects?

Comment: AFAIK there were only two different ghost actions there, going to Al Mualim's desk would show Altair jump through the window.  Others will just show him standing in the middle of the room.  Nothing particularly useful as far as I can tell.  Maybe a hint for what happens later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think they impact completion stats, but they are easter eggs for those of us who beat *AC1* and foreshadowing for future events in the game. They show some key stuff from Altaïr's genetic memory, as well as show that Ezio is suffering from the same genetic memory bleed as Desmond at that point.

Comment: I took it as Desmond seeing them, not Ezio.  There's no reason to think Ezio would have the bleeding effect, certainly not BEFORE he starts getting the Masyaf keys.

Answer (score 2):

Altair jumping through the window is seen in one of Altair's five memories.

I've finished the game 100% and didn't even notice those. So I would guess that looking at them is cool, but they don't impact on game completion.